# coinbase api call resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response

Tags: php, bitcoin, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I'm trying to integrate Coinbase Wallet PHP Library.

here is my code to get current BTC buy price

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Address;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account;

$apiKey = '**********';
$apiSecret = '*************';
$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$client = Client::create($configuration);

try {
    $buyPrice = $client->getBuyPrice('BTC-USD');
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
    echo '<hr/>';
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    echo '</pre>';

}
?>
```

above code work perfectly, but some time it throw following error

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\coinbase\vendor\coinbase\coinbase\src\HttpClient.php(137): Coinbase\Wallet\Exception\HttpException::wrap(Object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\coinbase\vendor\coinbase\coinbase\src\HttpClient.php(121): Coinbase\Wallet\HttpClient->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\coinbase\vendor\coinbase\coinbase\src\HttpClient.php(74): Coinbase\Wallet\HttpClient->request('GET', '/v2/prices/BTC-...', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\coinbase\vendor\coinbase\coinbase\src\Client.php(820): Coinbase\Wallet\HttpClient->get('/v2/prices/BTC-...', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\coinbase\vendor\coinbase\coinbase\src\Client.php(118): Coinbase\Wallet\Client->getAndMapMoney('/v2/prices/BTC-...', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\coinbase\index.php(16): Coinbase\Wallet\Client->getBuyPrice('BTC-USD')
#6 {main}
Client error: `GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/buy` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
```

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similiar issue connecting this API, but not using the libary.

I think it is some kind of protection from Cloudflare. I managed to circumvent it adding some additional headers to fake a "real" browser, especially the "User-Agent":

```
        $url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-EUR/spot';
        $response = wp_remote_get($url, array(
                'timeout' => 120,
                'headers' => array(
                    'CB-VERSION' => '2017-05-19',
                    'Accept' => '*/*',
                    'Accept-Language' => 'de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
                    'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
                    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 OPR/45.0.2552.882'
                )
            )
        );
```

(wp_remote_get is from WordPress)

Comment: Thank you, had the same issue and can confirm that a simple "myConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");" in java did it for me.